# Get span text inside <p> using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to extract text of span inside `<p>` tag. My html looks like this

```
<p itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/PostalAddress">

    <span itemprop="streetAddress">

       addressline1,line2,town,postalcode

    </span>

</p>
```

My vba code is

```
    Dim htmlele1 As HTMLDivElement
    For Each htmlele1 In doc.getElementsByTagName("span")
        If htmlele1.attributes.itemprop = "streetAddress" Then
            Range("c" & i).Value = htmlele1.innerText
        End If
    Next
```

But its not working. How can i fetch span text with attribute

Comment: Your `span` has no `name`attribute. Give it unique ID and use `getElementByID("span_id")`

Comment: Define 'its not working'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
For Each htmlele1 In doc.getElementsByTagName("span")
    If htmlele1.getAttribute("itemprop") = "streetAddress" Then
        Range("c" & i).Value = htmlele1.innerText
    End If
Next
```